# Forms Authentication shows login for PDF files only

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, safari, ria

I have a Silverlight application that is setting an auth cookie using Forms Authentication:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false)
```

This seems to work well, the app authenticates, and logs in.  The app can access services that are protected by Forms Authentication, but when it tries to access PDF documents with the same authentication scheme:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I can't figure out why it would require a login for one and not the other.  And to make it even worse it only asks for Authentication on a Mac using Safari.  It doesn't redirect to login except in that case.

Comment: How do you secure PDF files using forms authentications - are you using integrated pipeline in IIS7? I would suggest that you use tool such as Fiddler (not sure about the tool on Mac) to watch request/response - idea is to figure out the difference between request/response cycles when called from Mac/Safri against that from other browser/os combo.

Comment: Like you, I'm an avid Fiddler user.  On the Mac I use Wireshark.  It's very interesting.  I also checked the logs and they show the same thing.  It is apparently authenticated in the application, so most things will work, but there is no username in the logs and Wireshark shows a 302 Found then Object Moved to the login.  I read on another blog comment that it is because the HttpContext does not have a generic principal, apparently because of the difference in cookies on Safari OSX.  I'm going to add a global principal in my Global.asax and see what happens.